# Get screenwidth from javascript function and use as percentage

Tags: javascript, html

I have to resize table elements based on the screen's width. I'm not knowledgable about javascript or html, but I have to get this to work. I did not write the original asp page, nor can I change much about it.

For instance in the following code example, where `SCREENWIDTH` is the placeholder for a variable or function call:

```
<td>
  <div style="width:(SCREENWIDTH * 2 / 3)%">
    <input type="text" class="textfield" id="resourceref" name="resourceref"
      accesskey="E" onkeydown="infoChange('ref');" style="width: 90%">
  </div>
</td>
```

I was thinking of using a javascript function in which I call screen.width, and return this as the value of `SCREENWIDTH`, but my syntax doesn't seem to be right whether I put the function call in " and " or ' and '.

Perhaps there is another way of doing this, but this was my reasoning.

It was coded as simple percentages, but it didn't work correctly. This td, is in a table, that is in a frame which is part of a frameset of three vertical frames, and to the right there is another frame which obscures some of the table elements if the screenwidth is very narrow. I didn't write it this way, and I don't know much about frames, but I have to fix this. So I want to know what the screenwidth is, and adjust it suitably before I use it for the determination of the width of the td.

so if I have (and I might do more to the screenwidth besides simply returning it)

```
<script language="javascript">
function getScreenWidth()
{
    return screen.width; 
}
</script>
```

in the head tag, how must I then call this from the html?

So how can I get the screen's width as part of the determination of the td's width?

Comment: It doesn't make sense calculating percentages based on screen width in pixels. Am I missing something or couldn't you just set the width to 66% (2/3 of full width)?

Comment: have you tried adding `width` to your `table` in `%` say `70%`, the `table` will cover 70% of the frame no matter what the frame size is and the `td` and `tr` may have `100%`, they will cover the entire table no matter what the table size is

Answer (score 0):

Should just be able to do `screen.width` to get the screen width in pixels. Though, is there a particular reason you are not using `width: 66.666%` in this case?

Comment: I have one doubt, OP is assigning the `width` in `%` to a `div` which is inside a `td`, then no matter what, that `div` is gonna have a relative width to that `td` and not the screen's width, right?

Comment: With width: 66.666, yes, that is true, but getting the width based on screen.width, it will not

Comment: I was playing around on the W3schools HTML editor, since I became confused and wanted to see quick results. The div actually seems to help the resizing somehow. I read it somewhere, though I can't remember where it was suggested. I have no loyalty to the div. It could be removed if it posed some hindrance.

Comment: @bizzehdee, I edited the original post to explain why I'm not using plain percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Screen width and height is tricky because different browser will handle it different.
I would suggest to look at jquery the have some useful tools for sizing. Especially on resize events, etc.

Here is an example:

```
         $(window).resize(function() {   
           // event which gets fired on rezising
            $(window).height(); // the new height 
            $(window).width(); // the new width
          });
```

you can use this information for further calculations and styling of course...

for example

```
    $('#theDiv').width(function(){
   return $(window).width() * 0.66;
});
```

And it works unobtrusive (no inline javascript) just give the div an ID
HTH

Answer (score 0):

I use this function I wrote that reports correctly for every device I have tried...

This will allow you to calculate your percentages based on actual screen size. I start with iPad width (768) and calc % from there - (screenWidth/768)*100..

Hope this helps.

```
function getDeviceDimensions()                  // get the width and height ofthe viewing device based on its OS
{
    screenWidth = window.screen.width;                                                  // get the width
    screenHeight = window.screen.height;                                                // get the height 
    var computedPixelRatio =  (window.screen.availWidth / document.documentElement.clientWidth);                        // a more reliable measure of device pixel ratio due to android firefox bugs...
    computedPixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio >= computedPixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : computedPixelRatio;  // select whichever value is larger between pixel ratio methods
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)                                   // if the client is on an android system
    {
        screenWidth = screenWidth / computedPixelRatio;                                 // divide the reported width by the pixel ratio
        screenHeight = screenHeight / computedPixelRatio;                               // divide the reported height by the pixel ratio
    }
    //alert(screenWidth + " " + screenHeight + " " + window.devicePixelRatio + " " + computedPixelRatio);
}
```